# Upload file type not permitted even if explicitly registered as upload_filetypes in the db (multisite)

Tags: multisite, uploads, media-library

I am suddenly getting a `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons` while trying to upload some file extensions which used to work.

Specifically, `jpg doc txt ods` work, `rtf docx xls xlsx` are not allowed.

[image: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons]

- The file types are listed in *Network settings > Upload file types*

  [image: Network settings > Upload file types]
- I also checked in the database `upload_filetypes`.

  [image: wp_sitemeta > upload_filetypes]
- Also checked with `get_allowed_mime_types()`

  [image]
- Tried adding with `upload_mimes` filter - and a couple of plugins, checked `.htaccess` to no avail. I also tried with all the plugins off.
- Also, on the same shared hosting account there are other instances of WP where the uploading is not limited.

What could I do next?

Comment: nice quest @pax

Comment: Were you looged in  as admin?

Comment: yes, logged as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue that was introduced in 4.7.1:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39550

There is a plugin to workaround it for those having this problem. A fix will likely be in the next release.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-real-mime-check/

Comment: Using WP `v4.8` and still have this problem with `.xls` file. Had to install this plugin to workaround.

Comment: The issue is not "fixed", however it is "reduced". Even without that plugin, it is quite likely that if you opened your "XLS" file in Excel and then merely resaved it to another file, then you would find that that file would upload properly, no need for the plugin.